# Pressure change bottle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

How does the pressure change inside an bottle containing water as its slowly squeezed out. The volume of the bottle decreases when its squeezed, but water is pushed out so how does that relate. Are there any formulas outlining this.

Comment: More detail required. Are you talking about a "water rocket" with a pressurised bottle?

Comment: Pressure of what?

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of the shape of the bottle and the pressure that is applied on the open bottle, the pressure at a given point will exactly be equal to the height of fluid column above it. This is, considering that the process is quasi-static (the bottle is squeezed very slowly, which means there is enough time for all transient pressure fluctuations to damp down)
[image: Hydrostatic pressure]